# customizing csv writerow to fill empty values

Tags: python, csv

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv
keys=['a','b','c','Date','TimeStamp']
class NpWriter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #some logic
        pass

    def openFile(self,):
        path = self.settings.get('FILENAME')
        if not path:
            path = 'items.csv'
        self.csvfile = open(path,mode='w',encoding='UTF-8')
        self.writer = csv.DictWriter(self.csvfile,fieldnames=keys,)
        self.writer.writeheader()

    def processItem(self, item,):
        if 'images' in item.keys():
            item.pop('images')
        now = datetime.now()
        item['Date']= now.strftime('%b-%d-%Y')
        item['TimeStamp'] = int(datetime.timestamp(now))
        self.writer.writerow(item)
        return item
    def closeFile(self,):
        #print("\n\nClosed\n\n")
        self.csvfile.close()

example_input = [{'a':'test','b':2,'c':'test'},{'a':'','b':2,'c':'test'},{'a':'test','b':2,'c':''}]
```

is there a way to custmize the `csv.DictWriter` to replace empty values in the `writer.row` by a specific text i.e replace empty values by "Not Found", I know looping on the item would be easier but I need to do this way

expected out in csv

```
cat test.csv

a,b,c,Date,TimeStamp
test,2,test,Apr-03-2020,1585874076
Not Found,2,test,Apr-03-2020,1585874076
test,2,Not Found,Apr-03-2020,1585874076
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new dict with empty values replaced with the desired string as an argument for the `writerow` method:

```
self.writer.writerow({k: v or 'Not Found' for k, v in item.items()})
```

Comment: this works, but as I said I wanted to customize `writerow` method